# spark-submit not using YARN

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have setup a 5 node hadoop cluster with YARN,Spark is also set up on all the 5 nodes. I am using spark-1.5.0-cdh5.5.0

When i run

`spark-shell --master yarn --num-executors 3`

This starting up a shell as expected and is using yarn to get resources from RM. So, I am guessing that spark is using the hadoop conf files as expected. But when i do spark-submit

```
spark-submit word_count.py --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 3
```

This is trying to connect to spark master, which is believe is not required when running on yarn. Error below:

```
    16/11/08 00:18:31 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 47990.
16/11/08 00:18:31 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/11/08 00:18:41 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/11/08 00:18:41 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16/11/08 00:18:41 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/11/08 00:18:41 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.0.0.4:4040
16/11/08 00:18:41 INFO util.Utils: Copying /home/rshaik26/word_count.py to /tmp/spark-0a5348f8-5ba8-4906-89af-7499054b554e/userFiles-287b5d13-123a-4bd6-9fe3-489af2a502a1/word_count.py
16/11/08 00:18:41 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added file file:/home/rshaik26/word_count.py at http://10.0.0.4:47990/files/word_count.py with timestamp 1478544521986
16/11/08 00:18:42 WARN metrics.MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
16/11/08 00:18:42 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://ubuntuhdp2:7077...
16/11/08 00:18:42 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Could not connect to ubuntuhdp2:7077: akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
16/11/08 00:18:42 ERROR akka.ErrorMonitor: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.0.0.4:53411] -> [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: ubuntuhdp2/10.0.0.4:7077
]
akka.event.Logging$Error$NoCause$
16/11/08 00:18:42 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Could not connect to ubuntuhdp2:7077: akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
16/11/08 00:18:42 ERROR akka.ErrorMonitor: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.0.0.4:53411] -> [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: ubuntuhdp2/10.0.0.4:7077
]
akka.event.Logging$Error$NoCause$
16/11/08 00:18:42 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Could not connect to ubuntuhdp2:7077: akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
16/11/08 00:18:42 ERROR akka.ErrorMonitor: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.0.0.4:53411] -> [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: ubuntuhdp2/10.0.0.4:7077
]
akka.event.Logging$Error$NoCause$
16/11/08 00:18:42 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Could not connect to ubuntuhdp2:7077: akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
16/11/08 00:18:42 ERROR akka.ErrorMonitor: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.0.0.4:53411] -> [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: ubuntuhdp2/10.0.0.4:7077
]
akka.event.Logging$Error$NoCause$
16/11/08 00:18:42 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master ubuntuhdp2:7077
akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Actor[akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077/]/user/Master]
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:66)
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:64)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:74)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.execute(Future.scala:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:269)
    at akka.actor.EmptyLocalActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:512)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:545)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:535)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef.$bang(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:91)
    at akka.actor.ActorRef.tell(ActorRef.scala:125)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes$$anon$1$$anon$2.enqueue(Mailboxes.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.QueueBasedMessageQueue$class.cleanUp(Mailbox.scala:438)
    at akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox$MessageQueue.cleanUp(Mailbox.scala:650)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.cleanUp(Mailbox.scala:309)
    at akka.dispatch.MessageDispatcher.unregister(AbstractDispatcher.scala:204)
    at akka.dispatch.MessageDispatcher.detach(AbstractDispatcher.scala:140)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.akka$actor$dungeon$FaultHandling$$finishTerminate(FaultHandling.scala:203)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.terminate(FaultHandling.scala:163)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.terminate(ActorCell.scala:338)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:431)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:447)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:262)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:240)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
16/11/08 00:19:02 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://ubuntuhdp2:7077...
16/11/08 00:19:02 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Could not connect to ubuntuhdp2:7077: akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
16/11/08 00:19:02 ERROR akka.ErrorMonitor: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.0.0.4:53411] -> [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: ubuntuhdp2/10.0.0.4:7077
]
akka.event.Logging$Error$NoCause$
16/11/08 00:19:02 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Could not connect to ubuntuhdp2:7077: akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
16/11/08 00:19:02 ERROR akka.ErrorMonitor: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.0.0.4:53411] -> [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: ubuntuhdp2/10.0.0.4:7077
]
akka.event.Logging$Error$NoCause$
16/11/08 00:19:02 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Could not connect to ubuntuhdp2:7077: akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
16/11/08 00:19:02 ERROR akka.ErrorMonitor: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.0.0.4:53411] -> [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: ubuntuhdp2/10.0.0.4:7077
]
akka.event.Logging$Error$NoCause$
16/11/08 00:19:02 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Could not connect to ubuntuhdp2:7077: akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
16/11/08 00:19:02 ERROR akka.ErrorMonitor: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.0.0.4:53411] -> [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: ubuntuhdp2/10.0.0.4:7077
]
akka.event.Logging$Error$NoCause$
16/11/08 00:19:02 WARN client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master ubuntuhdp2:7077
akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Actor[akka.tcp://sparkMaster@ubuntuhdp2:7077/]/user/Master]
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:66)
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$$anonfun$resolveOne$1.apply(ActorSelection.scala:64)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:74)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:110)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutionContexts$sameThreadExecutionContext$.execute(Future.scala:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:269)
    at akka.actor.EmptyLocalActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:512)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.specialHandle(ActorRef.scala:545)
    at akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:535)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemoteDeadLetterActorRef.$bang(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:91)
    at akka.actor.ActorRef.tell(ActorRef.scala:125)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailboxes$$anon$1$$anon$2.enqueue(Mailboxes.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.QueueBasedMessageQueue$class.cleanUp(Mailbox.scala:438)
    at akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox$MessageQueue.cleanUp(Mailbox.scala:650)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.cleanUp(Mailbox.scala:309)
    at akka.dispatch.MessageDispatcher.unregister(AbstractDispatcher.scala:204)
    at akka.dispatch.MessageDispatcher.detach(AbstractDispatcher.scala:140)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.akka$actor$dungeon$FaultHandling$$finishTerminate(FaultHandling.scala:203)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.terminate(FaultHandling.scala:163)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.terminate(ActorCell.scala:338)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:431)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:447)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:262)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:240)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Please help me out if there is any config mistake

here is spark-env.sh

```
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS=-Dspark.driver.port=53411
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0/etc/hadoop/
SPARK_MASTER_IP=ubuntuhdp2
SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath):/usr/lib/hadoop-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*
```

spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.master                     spark://ubuntuhdp2:7077
# spark.eventLog.enabled           true
# spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://namenode:8021/directory
  spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
# spark.driver.memory              5g
# spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"
```

Comment: You are asking why is `spark.master` in `spark-defaults.conf` not replaced by `--master` flag in `spark-submit` (cause you have `spark.master` in `spark-defaults.conf`)??

Comment: @VladoDemcak Hi, Yes! and also if that's the case how did shell mode work with yarn?

Comment: I think you need `spark.master=yarn.client` in your `spark-defaults.conf` file.  Or `spark.master=yarn.cluster` if you wish to run in cluster mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe with:

```
spark-submit word_count.py --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 3
```

you said to [`spark launching`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) *"I want to submit `word_count.py` and my `[application-arguments]` are `--master yarn-cluster --num-executors 3`"* so he chose the default master.

Try following:

```
 spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 3 word_count.py
```

And yes this should submit spark to yarn and when you define `-cluster`, your application runs somewhere on cluster (on  "yarn resource node").

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my system. The clue was this log statement :

> numExecutors have been set to default : 2
>
> maxExecutors have been set to default : 2

Even when i increased the num of executors i got the same.

So the fix is simple :

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 3 word_count.py
```